# Interacting with a Database from Scheme

Tags: mysql, database, scheme

i try to learn scheme and as a test project i wanted to create a very simple website with 1-2 database queries (MySQL preferred, but PostgreSQL would be ok, too).

I know it's not really schemes domain but i still want to see how far i can come.
Sadly, it seems i'm already stuck at using a database and googling for "scheme database" or any other combination including this words was (as expected considering the double meaning of scheme in this case) not very helpful.

Can you give me any hints on how to access a database from a scheme program?

I read something about scheme code interfacing a mysql client program to do that but i'd prefer something more direct.

Thanks.

Comment: Which implementation of scheme are you using? Scheme48? PLT? Larcency? ... IIRC, there once was a PostgresSQL module for Scheme48/ScSH available. See http://www.scsh.net/resources/debase.html

Comment: I'm currently only using GNU Guile to play around, but as i just started Scheme programming i'm open to whatever suits my needs. Scheme48 seems to be the logical choice but if any other can do what i require then i will try it.

Comment: Check out Racket; it might have drivers you like:

http://planet.plt-scheme.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Guile already has a database interface that supports Postgres, MySQL and SQLite. It is 
called [Guile DBI](http://gna.org/projects/guile-dbi). Other Scheme implementations you may try are: [SISC](http://sisc-scheme.org/) (Can connect
to any JDBC compliant database, including MySQL) and [Spark-Scheme](http://vmathew.in/spark/) (Can connect to any 
ODBC compliant database, including MySQL and comes bundled with SQLite). Also note that most 
Scheme implementations has some form of Foreign Function Interface that will help you 
to write your own MySQL->Scheme Connector.